# UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I have a problem connecting a microservice with mongoDB in Docker in a ubuntu server
My application.properties:

```
#-------APP-------
spring.application.name=app-interventor
server.port=${PORT:0}

#-----MongoDb------
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=user
spring.data.mongodb.database=interventorApp
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true

#-----Eureka-------
eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka:8761/eureka

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

as initialize mongo in docker:

```
sudo docker network create appcity
sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo --network appcity -d mongo:4
sudo docker exec -it mongo bash
```

in shell:

```
mongo
use admin
db.createUser({user: "user", pwd: "user", roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}],mechanisms:["SCRAM-SHA-1","SCRAM-SHA-256"]})
exit
mongo -u user -p user
```

and it works fine,
To run the service I use

```
sudo docker build -t interventor:v1 .
sudo docker run -P --name interventor --network appcity interventor:v1
```

when deploying the service interventor

```
2021-12-03 07:15:26.590  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.interventor.InterventorApplication   : Starting InterventorApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 12.0.2 on bb6a574120a3 with PID 1 (/Interventor.jar started by root in /)
2021-12-03 07:15:26.596  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.interventor.InterventorApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-03 07:15:29.529  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-03 07:15:29.952  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 415 ms. Found 2 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-12-03 07:15:30.838  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=760288dd-e07a-3d43-bbbd-43a37033fd10
2021-12-03 07:15:32.821  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2021-12-03 07:15:32.856  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-03 07:15:32.857  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
2021-12-03 07:15:32.971  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-03 07:15:32.971  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6214 ms
2021-12-03 07:15:34.197  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-12-03 07:15:34.335  INFO 1 --- [l'}-mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:625075}] to mongo:27017
2021-12-03 07:15:34.335  INFO 1 --- [l'}-mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:625076}] to mongo:27017
2021-12-03 07:15:34.340  INFO 1 --- [l'}-mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=44144929}
2021-12-03 07:15:34.516  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2021-12-03 07:15:34.889  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2021-12-03 07:15:35.162  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3}] to mongo:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
2021-12-03 07:15:35.169  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'interventorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PInterventorRepository' defined in com.interventor.repository.PInterventorRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
2021-12-03 07:15:35.179  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4}] to mongo:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
2021-12-03 07:15:35.191  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-03 07:15:35.223  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-03 07:15:35.272 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'interventorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PInterventorRepository' defined in com.interventor.repository.PInterventorRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at com.interventor.InterventorApplication.main(InterventorApplication.java:19) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[Interventor.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[Interventor.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[Interventor.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[Interventor.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PInterventorRepository' defined in com.interventor.repository.PInterventorRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
```

that error comes out!!!

try to do it by docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4
    container_name: mongo
    hostname: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - $MONGO_HOST_PORT:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=$MONGO_DB
      - MONGO_DB_USERNAME=$MONGO_DB_USERNAME
      - MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=$MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - $MONGO_DATA_HOST_PATH:/data/db/
      - $MONGO_LOG_HOST_PATH:/var/log/mongodb/
      - $MONGO_INITDB_SCRIPTS_HOST_PATH:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    networks:
      - appcity
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: interventor:v1
    container_name: interventor
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=interventorApp
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE=$MONGO_DB
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_AUTO_INDEX_CREATION=$MONGO_AUTO_INDEX_CREATION
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_USERNAME=$MONGO_DB_USERNAME
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PASSWORD=$MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=$MONGO_DB
    networks:
      - appcity
networks:
  appcity:
    external:
      name: $NETWORK_NAME
```

but not work for me, I get the same error
Im trying to connect different services to mongo, so that each one of them has its own database and that everything is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with two configurations

One in application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://admin:123456@mongo:27017/busquedaApp?authSource=admin
```

And in docker, i created two users for mongo docker, like this:

```
sudo docker exec -it mongo bash
mongo
use admin
db.createUser({ user:'admin',pwd:'123456',roles:[ { role:'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin'}]});
db.auth('admin','123456');
db.createUser({ user:'user',pwd:'123456',roles:[ { role:'readWrite', db: 'testdb'}]});
db.auth('user','123456')
use testdb
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue, the solution in my case was to have `authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1` in the `url` as the following:

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://admin:secret@localhost:27017/discount_db?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1`

Comment: Works for me with Spring Boot 2.7.6 and Java 17, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newborn MongoDB created trough Docker on Windows, the default user dont have privileges of remote connecting on the new DB, so you'll need to update your user privilege

```
use admin

db.grantRolesToUser("YourUser", [{ role: "readWrite", db: "YourDb" }]);
```

Consider to create a dedicated user for your new db:

```
use YourDb

db.createUser({user: "YourUser", pwd: "pwd", roles : [{role: "readWrite", db: "YourDB"}]})
```

Notice that:

- the uri method on newer spring data doesnt work anymore.
- you **mustn't** mix uri and single proprieties authentification